# 2D game with 3D collision?

Tags: collision-detection, game-mechanics, physics

How do they do this bounce? Looks awfully complicated in 2D.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about 3D mapping like Josh said, i was just not believing they made this game with 3D.
XD

Comment: What game is this from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For bounces...**

If a heightmap was used, then a surface normal would be calculated at each impact point, by sampling local heights.

Otherwise, there is vector-based 3D geometry behind the scenes (literally) that already contains normals information based on its individual surfaces.

Either way, surface normals are used to produce accurate bounce vectors.

**For no bounces...**

This is where you only want the object to roll lazily down the surface. A heightmap's information should be enough to allow this, and is easier than setting up a mesh. You'd still need to perform some sort of interpolation, though, to smooth the motion, since the heights exist at different intervals.

Comment: i tried to achieve this result only with hightmaps and was having troubles with the normals computation, i skipped that step with normal maps but i will try again, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Store 3D collision data with your map, and perform the projectile simulation in 3D using that data.

Comment: You could also possibly get this result by combining a height map with a normal map and extrapolating to get the 3D data you need to simulate bounces and basic collision responses.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, the game works in a semi-3D world (it's most likely limited, e.g. it's just a plane with heights added on top; no complex things such as tunnels, platforms, etc.).

When rendering, this is transformed using a simple projection. For example, you could just use the following translation to get from a 3D world to a 2D screen representation:

```
fx(x, y, z) = x;
fy(x, y, z) = 0.5 * y + z;
```

In this example `x` would be the horizontal coordinate, `y` would be the coordinate facing to the back or the player and `z` would be the height above ground. By multiplying `y` you're essentially changing the camera's angel, while using an orthogonal projection (since there's no perspective correction/depth).

You could as well use the following transformations for `y`:

```
fy_birdseye(x, y, z) = y;
fy_side(x, y, z) = z;
```

Just remember that the game doesn't necessarily simulate a full 3D world. In fact it might be just 2D and such 3D collisions are resolved just in time using a minimal set of 3D calculations (i.e. only the direct Environment is built up with 3D primitives for collision).